# Swift EXC_BREAKPOINT crash on NSDateComponents access with iOS 10.x but not 11.x

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting EXC_BREAKPOINT crash reports for instances of the app running on iOS 10.3 but not on any newer iOS.

The problem seems to be in accessing `-[NSDateComponents minute]`.

This is Crashlytics summary:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe

# OS Version: 10.3.3 (14G60)
# Device: iPhone 5c
# RAM Free: 5.8%
# Disk Free: 17%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyApp                     0x1d91940 specialized static TimeUtility.annualCycleIndex(comps:comps0:) (TimeUtility.swift:53)
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1d05ecd5 -[NSDateComponents minute] + 8
2  MyApp                     0x1d91ad0 specialized static TimeUtility.exampleCall(date:date0:) (TimeUtility.swift:71)
3  MyApp                     0x1d82bac
```

The app is targeted iOS 9.
The actual code looks like so:

```swift
public class TimeUtility {

    public class func annualCycleIndex(comps: DateComponents, comps0: DateComponents) throws -> Int {

        // Abstract durations in seconds
        let minuteUnit = 60
        let hourUnit = 60 * minuteUnit
        let dayUnit = 24 * hourUnit
        let monthUnit = 30 * dayUnit
        let yearUnit = 12 * monthUnit

        // Full years count between date and date0

        guard let y0 = comps0.year, let m0 = comps0.month, let d0 = comps0.day, let hh0 = comps0.hour, let mm0 = comps0.minute, let ss0 = comps0.second else {
            throw MyAppError.processingError(function: #function, descr: "Failed to extract all required date components")
        }

        guard let y = comps.year, let m = comps.month, let d = comps.day, let hh = comps.hour, let mm = comps.minute, let ss = comps.second else {
            throw MyAppError.processingError(function: #function, descr: "Failed to extract all required date components")
        }

        // <--- XXX: Crash seems to happen somewhere here

        let t0 = y0 * yearUnit + m0 * monthUnit + d0 * dayUnit + hh0 * dayUnit + mm0 * minuteUnit + ss0
        let t = y * yearUnit + m * monthUnit + d * dayUnit + hh * dayUnit + mm * minuteUnit + ss

        return periodicCycleIndex(t: t, t0: t0, measure: yearUnit)
    }

    public class func exampleCall(date: Date, date0: Date) throws {

        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

        let comps0 = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: date0)
        let comps = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: date)

        let _ = try annualCycleIndex(comps: comps, comps0: comps0)

        // some other code...
    }

    public class func periodicCycleIndex(t: Int, t0: Int, measure: Int) -> Int {
        // Some other code...
        return 0
    }
}

public enum MyAppError : Error {
    case processingError(function: String, descr: String)
    case unknownError(error: Error)

    public var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .processingError(let f, let s):
            return "Failed to process request in function: \(f), description: \(s)"
        case .unknownError(let err):
            return "Unknown error: \(err)"
        }
    }
}
```

Could that be due to Objective-C somehow releasing NSDateComponent before Swift could access it? Wonder if anybody had something like this...

I have also tried accessing `-[NSDateComponents seconds]` and still same crash, only referring to the seconds component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was noticing that it was iPhone 5c, and later I saw a few other crashes – all coming from 32-bit devices. What happens is that under certain conditions Swift code is trying to access members of `NSDateComponents` as if they were 64 bit integers while they really were 32 bit Objective-C integers on those devices.

I have a suspicion that every new app release modern Swift code gets compiled in ways that could bring subtle incompatibilities with legacy 32-bit devices. Something to be aware of.

In my case, not using `NSDateComponents` and using `TimeInterval` instead which is `Double` and will stay double on any system helped to fix the crash.

Comment: Isn't it just an integer overflow? Remember `Int` is 32-bit long in 32-bit devices. The expression `let t = y * yearUnit...` overflows when `y >= 70` in 32-bit calculations. Anyway using `Double` seems to be the right solution, or `Int64` would work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The crash report confused me with `-[NSDateComponents minute] + 8` which made me think that Obj-C to Swift bridging failed while the `let t = y * yearUnit...` should be the cause. Key learning: **stay away from using NSDateComponents in calculations**... or convert to proper `IntXX` type